# Astronomy & machine learning. Where to start?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, radio-astronomy, data-analysis

I am a Computer Engineering major and would like to learn more about machine learning methods in Astronomy. What books or other resources could I use?

Comment: There may be some information on [Galaxy Zoo](https://www.galaxyzoo.org) - if I remember right they use volunteers online to identify galaxies, and the long term goal is to use the data to train search algorithms. [This blog entry may be useful](https://blog.galaxyzoo.org/2015/03/31/new-paper-galaxy-zoo-and-machine-learning).

Comment: Isn't asking for resources OT in this SE topic?

Comment: Voted close as this is very opinion based. The question is not related to facts of astronomy and astrophysics, just a request for resources. Personally I would suggest Google.

Comment: @FJC Data mining & machine learning are the methods of contemporary astronomy... I do not see how this is not related to the question.

Comment: @MarekSagan To clarify: you are not asking a question about methods of data mining or a specific use of machine learning, you are asking for book recommendations. Any answer will be one persons opinion on what is a good book/website resource, not a scientific researched fact or theory. Google gives you a lot of resources (books/websites/papers) to get you started, and if you can't understand a specific thing you can come back here to ask questions, but this isn't the correct forum for your question at this stage.

Comment: There is this coursera MOOC https://www.coursera.org/learn/data-driven-astronomy/home/welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recent [KISSCaltech lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAzC1fVksng) by Prof. Rob Fergus at the NYU might be of interest. *"An Overview of Machine Learning Approaches: Applications to Exoplanet Detection"*.

Comment: What about books? I would like to have some solid literature to come back to while I do my research...

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this, or at least give a description about why it's good? Right now this seems like a link-only answer.

Comment: @SirCumference Well, I first posted it as a comment. But since the question asks for "other resources", I thought that this current overview lecture of machine learning applied to exoplanets, from a renowned source, would be satisfactory as a partial answer. Since it might not yet be the content of text books. It's as valid as the question is formulated. It

Comment: @LocalFluff I'd say the answer still should have an overview on what the link is, why it's good, or at least some kind of elaboration.

Comment: This is an incredibly useful answer, thanks for that Fluffster.  (I'm not knocking SirCumf, by the way; my comment is coincidental.)